# changing button's color in react.js using array and usestate

Tags: reactjs, arrays, button

In this react.js code I should read button’s label from “categorylist”. When I click on a button ,the color changed for all buttons.
How can I change the color of each button by clicking on each one seperatly? Here is my code:

export default function CategoryPicker() {

const categorylist = [
{
label: "Fact",
id: 0,
},
{
label: "Event",
id: 1,
},
{
label: "People",
id: 2,
},
{
label: "Secure",
id: 3,
},
];
const [clsitemchanged, setclsitemchanged] = useState("blue");

return (


Select a category

```
  <style>{`
    .blue {color: rgb(59,130,246);  border: 2px solid rgb(59,130,246); background-color:white; padding:12px 15px; inline-size:80px; border-radius: 9999px; margin-inline-start:3px;}
    .white {color: white; border: 2px solid rgb(59,130,246); background-color:rgb(59,130,246); padding:12px 15px; inline-size:80px; border-radius: 9999px; margin-inline-start:3px;}
  `}</style>
  {categorylist.map((currentElement) => {
    return (
      <button
        className={clsitemchanged}
        key={currentElement.id}
        onClick={() =>
          setclsitemchanged((ctr) => (ctr === "blue" ? "white" : "blue"))
        }
      >
        {currentElement.label}
      </button>
    );
  })}
 
</div>
```

);
}

Answer (score 1):

You need either array of changed items or separate component for button, that remembers its state.

```
return
  {categorylist.map((currentElement) => {
    return (
      <button
        className={clsitemchanged[id]}
        key={currentElement.id}
        onClick={() =>
          setclsitemchanged((ctr) => ({...ctr, [currentElement.id]: (ctr[currentElement.id]==="blue" ? "white" : "blue")}))
        }
      >
        {currentElement.label}
      </button>
    );
  })}
```

or separate component:

```
const MyButton = ({children})=>{
const [clsitemchanged, setclsitemchanged] = useState("white")
<button
        className={clsitemchanged}
        onClick={() =>
          setclsitemchanged((ctr) => (ctr==="blue" ? "white" : "blue"))
        }
      >
       {children}
      </button>
}
```

```
 {categorylist.map((currentElement) => {
    return (
      <MyButton   
        key={currentElement.id}>
        {currentElement.label}
      </MyButton>
    );
  })}
```